# SQL Datareader failed to bind data to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, grid

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "select * from aspnet_Users where userName like '%@UserName%'";
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = reader;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    connection.Close();
}
```

I am trying to use connected model to search a user's data in a table but the GridView is always, never fills with data.

Comment: Did you tell the reader to read??Try calling reader.Read()

Comment: change your `LIKE` to `like '%' + @UserName+ '%'"`

Comment: @ughai, that doesnt make sense.

Comment: @serv - `'%@UserName%'` will be taken as a literal comparison and the value of the parameter will not be replaced.

Comment: check the value of the 1st column `DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(10) ='hi'
SELECT'%@UserName%' ,'%' +@UserName  + '%'`

Comment: @User2012384 - Not required to read the result if you assign the sqlreader object to databound control.

Comment: I tried them all, but no one worked :-(

Answer (score 1):

You parameter is acting as a string in your query because of single quotes you have include around the parameter. That is the reason it is not able to identify the parameter. Try this:-

```
string query = "select * from aspnet_Users where userName LIKE @UserName";
```

Then add it as parameter like this:-

```
command.Parameters.Add("@MyName",SqlDBType.NVarChar,40).Value ="%" + TextBox1.Text + "%";
```

Comment: @ÃhmëdSäßrý - What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @ÃhmëdSäßrý - Have you debugged the code? Are you getting any data. Please debug and check if you hitting the correct DB and if you are getting the records.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate gridview using `SqlDataAdapter`, your code look like this

```
        string query = "select * from aspnet_Users where userName like '%@UserName%'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
       GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I don't recommend using disconnected model with asp.net because it may cause a bottleneck problems.

Comment: But though, I tried it and there is exception 'Cannot find table 0.